# gnuplot: plotting from a binary file containing single column

Tags: plot, binary, gnuplot

I have a **binary file - 1 column, 20 values**.

The first 10 - x coordinate

the following 10 - corresponding y coordinates.

Is it possible to plot an x-y plot using gnuplot without preprocessing ?
If not, how can I preprocess the binary file (not converting it to a normal text file) for plotting in gnuplot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is not possible with gnuplot, although it offers massive options for `binary` files. One possibility to plot your file would be with the following python script (provided, your numbers are stored as `integer`), otherwise you must adapt it:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
np.savetxt(sys.stdout, np.fromfile(sys.argv[1], dtype='i4').reshape(2,10).transpose())
```

and plot it with

```
plot '< python script.py data.bin'
```

If you plan to work more with binary data files, I would suggest you to use the [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) file format.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, especially for the additional information of how to use python scripts in gnuplot. So essentially, I use python (or something else) to reformat data and save it as a text file before plotting in gnuplot.


I will look into the HDF5 file format. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @user2000581 If the answer solved your problem, [you might consider accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/about). I use HDF5 to save very large data files in a platform-independent binary format, which can then be plotted on-the-fly using [`h5totxt`](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/H5utils).